# What Kind of marriage happened between Shiva and Parvathy ? Did Kanyadaan happen ? What kind of Vivah it was?

Tags: shiva, marriage, parvati

How the wedding of Shiva and Parvathy happend ? Was there a Kanyadaan ? I think Parvathy chose Shiva herself.
I have heard that there was a Baraat in which Rakshas were also present.

What is the story of the wedding ?

What kind of Vivah it was ?  ( There are eight kind of Vivah )